# Invalid Scope : manage_notifications error while getting facebook notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook JavaScript API to get notifications using following code

I get my basic information using /me in Facebook API bit when I use /me/notifications it gives invalid scope error even though I specified scope value.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'my App id',
  cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                      // the session
  xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
  version    : 'v2.4', // use version 2.4
  read_stream: true,
  **manage_notifications: true,**
  user_groups: true
});

FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
});

FB.api(
  "/me/notifications",
  function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
      console.log("Notifications : " + JSON.stringify(response));
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("Notifications Error : " + JSON.stringify(response));
    }
  }
);
```

Check following image for more details

[image]

Comment: It gives following error

Comment: Invalid Scopes: manage_notifications. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

Answer (score 1):

"Invalid Scope" means that the permission does not exist.

`manage_notifications` is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Btw, `read_stream` and `user_groups` are deprecated too. Use `user_posts` and `user_managed_groups` instead.